# Hebrew not displaying with $http.get

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, hebrew

I want to `ng-repeat` a JSON object to display it. The JSON has hebrew characters.

This mock-up works perfectly:

```
var app = angular.module('gifApp', []);
app.controller('gifCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.gifs=[
        {"fileName": "Shake.gif", "name": "בני", "kw":["k1","k2"]},
        {"fileName": "WAT.gif", "name": "מיקי", "kw":["k1"]},
        {"fileName": "WTF.gif", "name": "אלון", "kw":["k3"]},
    ];
});
```

When I try to load the same information using `$http.get` the hebrew is broken.

```
var app = angular.module('gifApp', []);
app.controller('gifCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("path/to/file/gifs.json")
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.gifs = response.gifs;
        });
});
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It seems like the character encoding is not getting set properly in the response. This could lead to strange behavior in Hebrew, or other non-Romanized writing systems.

Comment: Where would I fix this?

In the angular app, the json, the html?

Comment: You would probably want to fix it in the $http.get call with some configuration parameters.

Comment: Has nothing to do with angular code...make sure response is being sent as utf-8

Comment: @charlietfl, How do you propose he does that with an HTTP GET request on a static JSON file without server configuration? The only way I can think of is by adding a header the GET request.

Comment: @JacobHeater server can be configured to set headers based on file extension Also possible the file wasn't saved in utf-8

Comment: @charlietfl, I agree with you that the problem should be addressed at the server level.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just copying a json file from another project that is in hebrew, and then copy pasted my content. It worked, even though the contents look the same. 
Could anyone explain what is the difference between the files?

Comment: I think the comment that @charlieftl made earlier about the file possibly not being saved in the correct encoding could have been the issue. It's hard to explain without inspecting the request and response in a tool like Fiddler.